# Only 3GB of RAM with PAE kernel on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ram, pae

I've installed 4GB RAM on my Thinkpad X60 running Ubuntu 12.04. Then I've installed PAE-enabled kernel. Now `uname -r` outputs

```
3.2.0-50-generic-pae
```

My CPU is capable of PAE:

```
$ grep pae /proc/cpuinfo
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor vmx est tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor vmx est tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm
```

BIOS reports 4096MB RAM.

Yet `free` outputs

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3088452    2264192     824260          0     168056     852880
-/+ buffers/cache:    1243256    1845196
Swap:      2085884          0    2085884
```

What's wrong?

Edit:
Here's the e820 dmesg section:

```
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009f000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000d2000 - 00000000000d4000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000dc000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bf6d0000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bf6d0000 - 00000000bf6df000 (ACPI data)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bf6df000 - 00000000bf700000 (ACPI NVS)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bf700000 - 00000000c0000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000f0000000 - 00000000f4000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec10000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fed00000 - 00000000fed00400 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fed14000 - 00000000fed1a000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fed1c000 - 00000000fed90000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000ff800000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
```

Comment: Do you have a built in display adapter?  If yes check in the BIOS and see how much RAM its using.

Comment: I don't know what's a built in display adapter. I have a notebook, so I have a built-in display. But I had 2GB before and most of it was available, so why would some adapter take 1GB all of a sudden?

Comment: Your machine has the Intel GMA 950, which uses shred RAm, so it might have used more after the upgrade.  See your BIOS for display adapter setting, or something similar.

Comment: In my BIOS config section I have a menu of Network, Serial portm Infrared, Modem, Parallel port, PCI, USB, Keyboard/Mouse, Display, Power, Alarm, Memory, SATA, CPU.
Under Display there's only Bood Display Device, HV expansion, Brightness.
Under memory there's only Extended Memory Test.
I've found http://askubuntu.com/questions/167042/64-bit-and-32-bit-12-04-report-1gb-less-ram. Maybe my motherboard suffers from similar issue.

Comment: It a possibility.  See if there is a BIOS update for you machine.  See this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144526/how-to-flash-a-bios-when-only-a-windows-binary-is-provided/144537#144537) on how to update under Ubuntu.

Comment: I've already made a BIOS update from Windows (dual boot) and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's probably a motherboard/BIOS issue and there's no workaround. Similar to [64-bit and 32-bit 12.04 report 1GB less ram](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167042/64-bit-and-32-bit-12-04-report-1gb-less-ram).

Comment: Chipset issue actually in this case.